# Function: Select MySQL and Return JSON

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Please help me, I need to implement a function in a separate module file and in the route where the render has to call this function receiving the query data:

```
function getSobre() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(`SELECT * FROM sobre ORDER BY cod DESC LIMIT 1`, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            } else {
                return resolve(results);
            }
        });
    });
}

const data = {
    title: getSobre().then(data => {
        /*
         * HERE How do I return this "data" to the "title:" ?????????????
         */
    }),
    name: 'Fabio',
    profession: 'Analista'
}
module.exports = data;
```

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750668/how-to-set-json-value-on-the-ejs-page

Answer (score 1):

`db.query` is a Js callback . Which will wait for the result , then return anything.

So data will always be empty since it is getting returned much before `db.query` getting full resolved

You should wrap this in a native promise, and then resolve the promise :

```
function getTabela{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // The Promise constructor should catch any errors thrown on
            // this tick. Alternately, try/catch and reject(err) on catch.
            let sql = "SELECT * FROM sobre ORDER BY cod DESC LIMIT 1";
            var data = {};

            db.query(sql, (err, results, fields) => {

                if (results.length > 0) {

                      resolve(fields)

                } else {
                    console.log('Erro: ' + err);
                }
            });
        });
}

getTabela().then(function(rows) {
    // now you have your rows, you can see if there are <20 of them
}).catch((err) => setImmediate(() => { throw err; }));
```

This way you should always have the data which is expected out of the query.

Comment: Now you modified the entire according to the answer.. Please keep the original question and add doubts as a part of comment. People coming to this question after few months, will be confused by seeing the answer, which does not make much sense after your edit. Remember that it should be useful for the community not just you :)