# How to set JSON value on the ejs page

Tags: javascript, java, html, mysql, node.js

I need to return JSON fields on my EJS page but it is coming blank, can someone help me:

**site-model.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('./../../database/config');
const connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

function getAbout (query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) return reject(err)
            resolve(rows)
        });
    });
}

module.exports = (async function () {
    const result = await getAbout('SELECT * FROM sobre ORDER BY cod DESC LIMIT 1');
    return result;
})()
```

**site.js** file where I import **site-model.js** and render the ejs page by passing the values:

**site.js**

```
var about
(async function () {
  about = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await require('./site-model')))
})()

module.exports = {

  pageSite: (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('About here: ', about);//Console ok, JSON is returning

    res.render('./site/index', { dados: about });// Help here

  },

}
```

My ejs page that receives the data from the render data:

```
<!-- Título -->
<div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="300ms">
     <h2><%= dados.titulo %></h2><!-- Help Here -->
</div>

<!-- Sub-Título -->
<div class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="300ms">
     <h4><%= dados.sub_titulo %></h4><!-- Help Here -->
</div>
```

**See the return of the console:**
[image: See the return of the console:]

**h4 and h2 coming empty:**
[image: h4 and h2 coming empty]

Comment: [JSON fields](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)?

Answer (score 0):

Your console shows that `about` is an array

Your're problem should be solved by:

`res.render('./site/index',  {dados: about[0]}  );`

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I managed to reach a satisfactory result, see:

**site-model.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('./../../database/config');
const connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

function select(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) return reject(err)
            resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {

    getSobre: (async function () {
        const result = await select('SELECT * FROM sobre ORDER BY cod');
        return result;        
    })(),

}
```

**site.js** (render)

```
const funcao = require('./site-model');

var sobre

(async function () {
  sobre = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await funcao.getSobre))
})()

module.exports = {

  pageSite: (req, res, next) => {

    res.render('./site/index', {
      TBSobre: sobre
    });
  },

}
```

**Page index.ejs**

```
   <!-- Preenche dados vindos do MySQL -->
   <% TBSobre.forEach(function(row){ %>
   <!-- Título -->
   <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="300ms">
        <h2><%= row.titulo %> </h2>
   </div>

   <!-- Sub-Título -->
   <div class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="300ms">
        <h4><%= row.sub_titulo %></h4>
   </div>
<% }); %>
```

[**Result Here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IQx9.png)

**Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**